# FTP Server Active Mode Not able to connect

Tags: windows-10, ftp, filezilla, winscp

I'm unable to connect to FTP server via Active Mode.

```
Filezilla with Active mode setting
/*******************************************************************************/
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:  Could not connect to server
/*******************************************************************************/

Windows Command Prompt (After disabling Passive mode in Internet Options)
/*******************************************************************************/
ftp> open
To xx.xx.xx.xx
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx.
Connection closed by remote host.
ftp>
/*******************************************************************************/
```

I have checked via port scan, port 21 & 80 are open.
I have added firewall exception & disabled antivirus

---

Update from Server Admin: He is able to connect & following is the log:

```
Status:    Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx:21...
Status:    Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:    220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER Username
Response:    331 Password required for Username.
Command:    PASS ********
Response:    230-Welcome to ftp.site.com
Response:        Access to this site is monitored and logged.
Response:        Access is restricted to Authorized users only.
Response:        If you are not authorized to access this service please disconnect now.
Response:        If you encounter any problems, please send a mail to admin@service.net for any problems with this service.
Response:    230 User Username logged in.
Command:    SYST
Response:    215 Windows_NT
Command:    FEAT
Response:    211-FEAT
Response:        SIZE
Response:        MDTM
Response:    211 END
Status:    Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status:    Logged in
Status:    Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:    257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:    200 Type set to I.
Command:    PORT 192,168,0,201,226,200
Response:    200 PORT command successful.
Command:    LIST
Response:    150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /bin/ls.
Response:    226 Transfer complete.
Status:    Calculating timezone offset of server...
Command:    MDTM Global.asax
Response:    213 20080825114103
Status:    Timezone offset of server is -21600 seconds.
Status:    Directory listing of "/" successful
```

---

Update: Finally the server admin agreed to look into the issue and asked for the IP used for connection. After changes from their end; the connection & login is successful, but, directory listing is giving error.

```
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PORT 192,168,1,100,192,167
Response:   500 Invalid PORT Command.
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Comment: You need to open up port 20 as well so ensure 20 and 21 are both opened.

Comment: I conveyed to The Admin of that Server I;m connecting to. He in turn sent me screenshots that he is able to connect without issue.

Comment: But from where is he connecting? Is he at the same location as you are? As he is using a local IP I'd assume not?

Comment: I'm also not sure what port 80 has to do with this any as that's typically HTTP web traffic and not related to FTP. Read over http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html for explanation of FTP regarding active vs passive, etc. Read over https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS and the implicit and explicit section for the ports needed with those protocols.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT They are using just straight insecure active FTP. (he has selected insecure option in the Filezilla site settings & also selected active). Port 80 was mentioned just as an information, on what the port scan showed.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT The Log is from Filezilla and the Admin has also sent screenshot which show the transfer mode is set to "Active" & Encryption type is "Only use plain FTP(insecure)"

Comment: As a simple test, totally disable your windows firewall and then attempt to make the active connection. If it fails then, perhaps try the same but from a different Internet connection if you can and with the FW disabled still. If it works, then your Windows FW is blocking the active random high port that attempt to connect to your client machine. I'm curious what result you get if you try a passive connection though just to confirm regardless of the screen shots sent.